# Reactor Sinks.Many with variable replay

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Assume that I want a flight arrival `Flux`. The `Sink` would be based on the following class.

```
class Flight {
      String  code;
      Date    eta;
      boolean arrived;
}
```

A `Map` of `code` -> `Flight` would be the actual `Sink`. New flights can be added (`emit`) and `eta` can change (causing `emit`). Arrivals are emitted as `arrived=true` then deleted from the `Map` on flight arrival (for simplicity's sake).

If I were to have **one** `Sinks.many().multicast().replay()` how can I remove previous `eta` changes and remove "arrived" flights from the internals of the Sink, such that a **new** `Subscriber` would not get "everything", but the latest of each inbound `Flight`, minus arrivals?

I suspect that I would need to create a new `Sinks.many().unicast()` for each new `Subscriber` and `emit` the latest content from the `Map` to the new `Subscriber` and continue to `emit` updates from `Map` change events.

However, how do I keep track of these `Sinks` so that I know which `Sinks` to `emit` to? And how do I know when a `Sink` becomes unsubscribed\disposed, so that I can stop `emit` to that disposed `Sink`?

I could do the tracking of subscribers via `Flux.create(FluxSink)` `onRequest()` `onDispose()` etc. which effectively gave me a `unicast()` Am I missing the difference between `FluxSink` and `Sinks`?

Comment: replay does what it says: it replays the "timeline of events" up to either a fixed number of events or a duration... so that doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job

Comment: @SimonBaslé (I feel privileged that you answered :-) . My issue with replay is that neither Duration nor size is sufficient. For sure, I can filter junk later in the Flux, however I was wondering if there was a way of accessing the "collection" which replay() uses, so that I can remove this junk beforehand (reduce the size of the replay's "collection"?). The only other solution as I see it, is to create a Sink for each new subscriber. Is that the recommend way to go?

Comment: you cannot access the internals of the sink, and it seems to me you have a per-Subscriber oriented use case anyway?

Comment: @SimonBaslé Thanks. And on the topic of capturing cancel/dispose via `Sinks`, is it just a case of `emit` and capturing `Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_TERMINATED` or `FAIL_CANCELLED`?

Comment: that is correct, you need to check these `EmitResult`s. Still, I wonder if the `Map` as the source of truth is the right data structure. Or if the `Flux<Flight>` is the most useful flux representation for that case, so I would further explore on that side of things if I were you